# javascript regular expression to check other than characters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to compare one string with an other string.

Suppose  `textbox1`  contains `"this is my requirement"` and `textbox2` contains `"check textbox`".

I need to take first word of each textbox (i.e. `this` and `check`) and compare them. An exception should be thrown if they are not the same.

The texts might consist of special characters, numbers, anything, but I only need the first words of these texts.

Could anybody tell me a regular expression for this?

Comment: If(Homework){ Add Homework Tag};

Comment: You don't need regular expression for this. Just split the text and compare the first words.

Comment: This should help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(\S+)/.exec(str)[1]
```

that will give you the first word of any string, and then you can compare the two... is that what you want?  Or if you want to ignore leading whitespace:

```
/^\s*(\S+)/
```

e.g.:

```
var rx = /^(\S+)/;

if(rx.exec(textbox1.value)[1] != rx.exec(textbox2.value)[1]){
    // do stuff
}
```